# Modifying bootstrap dropdown menu for full width dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Example so far [here](http://lwm.github.io/fiddle_example/homepage.html)

code [here](https://github.com/lwm/lwm.github.io/tree/master/fiddle_example)

Simply, I have a menu with 8 items in it (the topmost menu). We are using a 12 item width grid in bootstrap and want the dropdown part of each menu (that appears when clicked) to be full width of the container.

Something similar to the navigation menu [here](http://www.adp.dit.ie)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery you can find the height of the window and set the drop down div to this height minus the header height. Here is jQueries `.outerHeight()` https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/